# python3 pathlib mkdir Permission denied

Tags: python-3.x, filesystems

This code raised exception when I tried to create a sub dir `./test/123`  under `./test/`. And after examine the permission, I found that dir `./test` created by this code has `d-w----r--`, which is strange...If I mkdir in the terminal, that dir will have `drwxr-xr-x` permission.

```
from pathlib import Path
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Path('./test')
    p1.mkdir(644, parents=True, exist_ok=True)

    p2 = Path('./test/123')
    p2.mkdir(644, parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```

```
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/pathlib.py", line 1267, in mkdir
    if not exist_ok or not self.is_dir():
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/pathlib.py", line 1358, in is_dir
    return S_ISDIR(self.stat().st_mode)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/pathlib.py", line 1168, in stat
    return self._accessor.stat(self)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'test/123'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pathlib expects an octal integer instead of decimal. You can denote octal by preficing your mode bits `644` with `0o`, i.e. `0o644`. `644` decimal translates to `1204` in octal which imposes permissions you are seeing there.

Also, to traverse a directory structure you require both read and execute permissions on it, so I would recommend using `0o755` instead of `0o644`.

The Unix command line chmod assumes octal whereas your python pathlib library does not. Hope this helps.